# AWS WAF whitelist port access

Tags: amazon-waf

I have attached AWS WAF to ALB. I have exposed a service through port 5000 and it should only be accessed from certain IP range. How such IP whitelisting can be done in WAF ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IPSet based on your IP range.

> An IP set provides a collection of IP addresses and IP address ranges
> that you want to use together in a rule statement. IP sets are AWS
> resources.

Please refer to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-ip-set-managing.html) for creating and managing an IPSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ip set as told in the last answer ,
Then you'll have to create a rule that allows any request for this ip set,
and give it the highest priority so it applies first for every request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).